# What sort of attacks could be performed by an attacker who can set environment variables?

Tags: attacks, attack-vector, environment-variables

If an attacker can set environment variables at will, what attacks can be performed using this advantage, and what degree of control can the attacker take?

Comment: From the war games I played, I don't know if this is still possible (it was long ago), an environment variable could be used to avoid stack overflow protections, so redirecting the code to variable's address may spawn a shell.

Comment: The obvious one is `PATH`. If I type a simple command such as `ls` within a compromised environment, then any malicious program can be executed. If I use only absolute paths such as `/usr/bin/ls` then `PATH` no longer takes effect.

Comment: You should limit the scope if your question. 'what attacks' is a seemingly endless list. Perhaps asking for an example attack so we can know easily whether your question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

What about LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Unix/Linux or PATH on Windows? If I manage to get a malicious notepad.exe into C:\windows\temp, I can add this path as first element in the PATH and the malicious file will be executed instead of the real one.

Comment: Good point, I was thinking more in terms of server processes.

Comment: Then replace notepad.exe by sth that is called frequently on a server...

Answer (score 1):

This is really rather too broad a question for a direct answer.

It depends a lot on the OS and other applications that may be in use. Many applications may take some level of configuration from environment variables.

For example, many node.js applications will take a variable that determines whether it runs in a production or development mode. If an attacker can force it into development mode, the attacker may be able to find out information not presented in production mode.

However, I would have thought that there are far easier attacks. If someone has sufficient access to change environment variables, they may well have other access too.